# Why do I hear ますから (masukara) so often at the end of sentences?

Tags: set-phrases, phrases

Yesteday, I was watching [this](https://myanimelist.net/anime/10165/Nichijou) anime.

One of the characters said ますから (I'm not very sure, it sounded like "mascara") twice in the same scene.

Google Translate translates the phrase as "Because it is."

Could anyone tell me what it means in example contexts and why it goes at the end of sentences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

~ます is a very common way to end a verb. And から means because. So what was said was likely stating a reason or answering a question.

For example, the conversation could have been:

> Q: "Why did you buy such a big car"
>
> A: "Because I have a large family"
>
> Q: 「なぜそんなに大きい車を買ったのですか？」
>
> A: 「家族がたくさんい**ますから**」

Also, the verb in ます ＋ から can be used after a verb at the end of the sentence when the remainder of the predicate can be understood contextually.

> はい、行き**ますから**

Which literally translates to "I going, so..." and the rest of the sentences is implied. So they listener would understand that you are ending the conversion and going somewhere.

you could also hear it in a context like

> 「はい、お祈りし**ますから**」

Which means "Alright I'm going to pray, so...." And the listeners would understand that they should now be quiet and listen to the prayer. Or

> 「みなさん、もう行き**ますから**！」

Which is like "Guys, I'm leaving, so... (get in the car, hurry up etc.)

There are many other usages, but that should give you a good idea of why you hear it so much.