# Clarifying the purpose of から at the end of that sentence

Tags: particle-から

I recently read that sentence :

> 毎日{まいにち}、ねる前{まえ}に、おふろに入{はい}るといいですよ。つかれがとれます**から**。

I know から roughly means "because" or "from" and I carefully read [this thread](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/58773/why-do-i-hear-%E3%81%BE%E3%81%99%E3%81%8B%E3%82%89-masukara-so-often-at-the-end-of-sentences) about some of its usages.

However, I'm not sure if those usages apply to this particular sentence.

I'd translate it to :

> Every day, before you go to bed, you could have a bath. Your tiredness would disappear.

Or maybe it's more like :

> Take a bath every day before you go to bed, because if you do so, your tiredness will go away.

What is the purpose of から here? How can I apply the basic pattern **[Sentence 1] から、[Sentence 2]** pattern to that sentence ?

Comment: から can be added to a sentence to denote that it is a reason. It is used more widely than "because" in English and sometimes just doesn't translate easily.  Your second translation preserves the "reason" implied in the original. Another alternative is to use "so". Take a bath ... so your tiredness will go away.

Comment: Real life doesn't always work like a text book. Maybe your so keen to give this advice about taking a bath that you forget to give the reason first.

Comment: @G-Cam, your comment actually feels like a good answer to me. I understand that から can just be added at the end of a sentence (that one in particular) to clarify why you should do what you were told before. Also, would it sound weird to just not say it (again, at the end of that sentence in particular) ? If you could write an answer, I'd gladly accept it as the right one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated by G-Cam in the comments, `から` can also be used to denote a **reason**, a **purpose** for doing something. It has a wider meaning that just "because" in English.

> *It is used more widely than "because" in English […]. Your second translation preserves the "reason" implied [by から].* **G-Cam**

The sentence could then be translated as:

> Take a bath every day before you go to bed **in order for** your tiredness to go away.

Added at the end of a sentence (that one in particular) helps clarify **why** you should do what you were told before.

In Japanese, many kinds of sentence ending particles are used and often allow the speaker to make the tone of the sentence softer.

Answer (score 1):

The から in this case is used to introduce a reason/cause as to why it is good to take a bath before going to bed.